# Automation Testing: How to Fix this issue?

Tags: selenium, switch-statement

```
XSSFWorkbook wbk = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
    XSSFSheet sheets = wbk.getSheet("Sheet1");
    Iterator row = sheets.iterator();
    while (row.hasNext()){
        Row  rowItr = (Row) row.next();
        Iterator cellItr = rowItr.cellIterator();
        while (cellItr.hasNext()){
            @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
            Cell cell1 = (Cell) cellItr.next();
        /*  switch (cell1.getCellType()){
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                data.add(cell1.getStringCellValue());
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                data.add(cell1.getNumericCellValue());
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                data.add(cell1.getBooleanCellValue());/*
```

In the commented line I am getting an error displaying

> " cast The method getCellType() is undefined for the type Table.Cell "

. Why I am getting this error and how to fix it.

Comment: Have you imported the packages for Cell? `import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;`

Comment: I am so sorry for Replying you late .. The issue is fixed at that day it self ..Thanks for the help .

Comment: You are welcome..